# Deactivation Hook does not remove database

Tags: plugins, sql

If I deactivate the plugin, the database table does not get removed. It is removed only when i delete the plugin. Here's my code:

```
<?php
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_remove_database' );
function my_plugin_remove_database() {
     global $wpdb;
     $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sandbox';
     $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name";
     $wpdb->query($sql);
     delete_option("my_plugin_db_version");
}   ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. It is strongly recommended that you look for similar questions and do some research yourself. wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask This duplicate question has an answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169145/delete-tables-from-database-when-deleting-plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable plugin / plugin action via theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12163/disable-plugin-plugin-action-via-theme)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete tables from database when deleting plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169145/delete-tables-from-database-when-deleting-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

```php
function my_plugin_remove_database()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $db_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'sandbox';  // table name
    $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $db_table_name";
    $rslt=$wpdb->query($sql);
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_remove_database' );
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've changed please? At first glance you're just capturing the result of the query in a variable but then doing nothing with it. (You could at least log errors in the error log even if we can't report success here - I'm not sure?) What were you trying to do?